# Error when passing an int EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=1 Swift Xcode ios

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop

I'm getting an error when passing a let variable as a tag in a for loop, but not when I replace the variable with a number. I can println(i) and return a number. 
Why wont accept it as a key?

I have also tried setting a var as a counter with the same results

I get an error in:
swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional

full error:
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=1, subcode=0x1001ee4b0)

```
   func updateThing() {
    for (i, img) in enumerate(thingState) {
        switch img  {
        case 0:
            image = UIImage(named: "0.png");
             break
        case 1:
            image = UIImage(named: "1.png");
             break
        case 2:
            image = UIImage(named: "2.png");
             break
        default:
            image = UIImage(named: "x.png");
        }
    thing = self.view.viewWithTag(i) as UIButton;
    thing.setImage(image, forState: .Normal);
    }
```

But if I replace the i with a number there is no error and the image with the specified tag changes, and if I println(i) I get a number for each pass

```
thing = self.view.viewWithTag(2) as UIButton;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to be sure your views are Buttons, else it will fail to cast your view.

```
func updateThing() {
    for (i, img) in enumerate(thingState) {
        switch img  {
        case 0:
            image = UIImage(named: "0.png");
             break
        case 1:
            image = UIImage(named: "1.png");
             break
        case 2:
            image = UIImage(named: "2.png");
             break
        default:
            image = UIImage(named: "x.png");
        }
        if let thing = self.view.viewWithTag(i) as? UIButton {
             thing.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
        }
    }
}
```

The optional cast operator (`as?`) is preferred to the cast operator(`as`) since it doesn't make your app crash when it fails to cast.

Oh and semicolons are useless in Swift :)

### EDIT:

In the latest Swift version, `as` has been replaced with `as!`, but `as` still exists.

- `as!` is used to force cast with no check and is prone to craches. You mainly use it to down cast and you're absolutely sure of the type of the object.
- `as` can be used as an upcast such as `CAShapeLayer` to `CALayer` or other special cases like `[NSObject:AnyObject]` to `NSDictionary`. Making downcast will fail to compile.

Comment: Thank you! that worked, and I understand why now too

Comment: There's three types of casts now, I updated my answer in consequence.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you do not declare `i` but take it implicitly from `thingState`. Without seeing the declaration of the latter it's hard to tell, but I guess you need to do

```
thing = self.view.viewWithTag(Int(i)) as UIButton
```

And yes: semicolons are superfluous; as well as the `break`

Comment: the global `enumerate` function returns a tuple with an index and the object. I didn't see the type of index in the Swift doc

Comment: The index is taken from the declaration of `thingState`. I suppose it's something like `[String:AnyObject]` and not `[Int:AnyObject]`. So the compiler takes the `String`. If you cast it with `Int(...)` you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is to delete button by your mistake.
and You must see Your StoryBoard Screen or Xib file.
I think You Deleted Button.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, i tried Shift+Cmd+K to clean the project and it fixed the problem